# HTML horizontal alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a div in which theres an image and an text.

```
<div class="logo">
        <img src="images/car_logo.png" alt="logo" width="100px" height="100px">
        <h1>Some text</h1>
      </div>
```

Right now, the logo is above the text. I want that the logo would be on left and text on right while the whole div is on the left side of the page, so I can add something else on the far side of right page.

Comment: You need to style your image with float or with display:inline-block.

Comment: Post the CSS you've tried.

Comment: The text is above without any css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show more of your code. Nonetheless, you want to style the h1 element to "display: inline-block;" or "display: inline;" should work also. You want to have your div "logo" to "float: left;" and "display: inline-block;".

Comment: Im sorry I will post better next time, however your advice worked. Thank you very much

Comment: All fine! Mark this answer as solved so people don't continue to comment! Hope the design goes well!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using flex:

```css
.logo{
  display:flex;
}

.l-logo{

}

.l-text{

}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <div class="l-logo">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="logo" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div class="l-text">
      <h1>Some text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this, hope it helps.

```css
.logo > h1{ float:left;padding-left:10px; }
 .logo > img { float:left;border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div class="logo">
   <img src="images/car_logo.png" alt="logo" width="100px" height="100px">
   <h1>some text</h1>
</div>
```